# Creating Embeddable JS that requires jQuery, how to not overwrite existing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I am in the process of creating a JS snippet that users can include on their site. This snippet depends on jQuery (and Backbone). It works fine if I embed it in a site that doesn't already have jQuery loaded, but if it does, it's still generally okay, unless they have written custom jQuery extensions, which then get overwritten.

Is it possible to scope my jQuery so that it doesn't overwrite any existing jqueries?

Comment: it all depends where they include your script. you can specify that someone puts your <script> tag above all the other jquery stuff so that any conflicts get overwritten, or the other way around if you want yours to take precedence

Comment: @guavacat. True, this is always an option. I wonder if its possible to scope jquery in some way that I dont have to do this though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had a very similar issue.

We were using Requirejs 1.0.6, then we used segment.com to integrate analytics into our webapp. It included another js called inspectlet.js, which used to redefine jquery.

Since, our original application had jquery extensions, all were gone the moment we integrated the analytics code, because jquery was redefined.

The problem in our case was inspectlet.js was redefining jquery in amd/require, which when upgraded to requirejs2.0.5 resolved.

I suggest to use the same code as inspectlet.js to use/define jquery.

http://cdn.inspectlet.com/inspectlet.js

```
var __inspsetjqueryback = false;
if (typeof jQuery != "undefined"){
__inspsetjqueryback = jQuery;
}

var __inspsetdollarback = false;
if (typeof $ != "undefined"){
__inspsetdollarback = $;
}

if(typeof jQuery != "undefined") jQuery.noConflict(true);
//define jquery - execution execution code goes here...
var $i = $i || jQuery.noConflict(true);

if(__inspsetjqueryback !== false){
jQuery = __inspsetjqueryback;
}

if(__inspsetdollarback !== false){
$ = __inspsetdollarback;
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach! I will look into this.

Comment: I can not recommend this approach. 

I just tried to use Inspectlet in my project that uses an AMD loader (CujoJS Curl) and it failed to load at all due to the embedded jQuery code being AMD compatible and, as a result, attempting to re-define the already loaded jquery AMD module.